# Javascript function using promises and not returning the correct value

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

As a relative beginning in Javascript development, I'm trying to understand this problem I'm encountering in a function I've built that will be a part of the code to connect to a postgreSQL database.

In this function, I'm using the knex query builder method to check if a table exists in a remote database, and this method resolves to a boolean that indicates whether the string you specified matches with a table of the same name in the database.  I've a provided a sample example of the knex syntax so people better understand the function.

```
knex.schema.hasTable('users').then(function(exists) {
  if (!exists) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('users', function(t) {
      t.increments('id').primary();
      t.string('first_name', 100);
      t.string('last_name', 100);
      t.text('bio');
    });
  }
});
```

I am trying to make my function return a boolean by using the .every Array method, which checks each array and should every index pass the condition defined, the .every method should return a true value, otherwise false.  I've built a function which takes an array of schema keys, or names of tables, and passes it to the .every method.  The .every method then uses the knex.schema.hasTable method to return a true or false.

My concern is that through many different configurations of the function, I have not been able to get it to return a correct value.  Not only does it return an incorrect value, which may have something to do with .every, which I believe can return "truthey" values, but after defining the function, I will often get a "Function undefined" error when calling it later in the file.  Here is a sample of my function - again I think it is moreso my poor understanding of how returns, promises and closures are working together, but if anyone has insight, it would be much appreciated.

```
var schemaTables = ['posts','users', 'misc'];

// should return Boolean
function checkTable() {
    schemaTables.every(function(key) {
    return dbInstance.schema.hasTable(key)
        .then(function(exists) {
            return exists;
            });
    });
}

console.log(checkTable(), 'checkTable function outside');
// console.log is returning undefined here, although in other situations,
   I've seen it return true or false incorrectly.
```

Comment: `.every()` evaluates synchronous results and uses a synchronous callback, it doesn't know what to do with callbacks whose result is in an async promise.  Basically, you can't use `.every()` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is not working properly for two reasons:

1. You are not returning the in the `checkTable` function declaration, so it will always return undefined.
   You should write:

```js
function checkTable() {
  return schemaTables.every(function(key) {
    return dbInstance.schema.hasTable(key)
      .then(function(exists) {
        return exists;
      });
  });
}
```

Anyway **you will not get what you want** just adding return. I'll explain why in the second point.

2. `Array.prototype.every` is expecting a truthy or falsey value *syncronously* but what the `dbInstance.schema.hasTable` returns is a Promise object (and an object, even if empty, is always truthy).

---

What you have to do now is checking if the tables exist *asynchronously*, i'll show you how:

```js
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var schemaTables = ['posts', 'users', 'misc'];

function checkTable(tables, callback) {

  // I'm mapping every table into a Promise
  asyncTables = tables.map(function(table) {
    return dbInstance.schema.hasTable(table)
      .then(function(exists) {
        if (!exists)
          return Promise.reject("The table does not exists");
        return Promise.resolve("The table exists");
      });
  });

 // If all the tables exist, Promise.all return a promise that is fulfilled 
 // when all the items in the array are fulfilled.
 // If any promise in the array rejects, the returned promise 
 // is rejected with the rejection reason.
  Promise.all(asyncTables)
    .then(function(result) {
      // i pass a TRUE value to the callback if all the tables exist, 
      // if not i'm passing FALSE
      callback(result.isFulfilled());
    });

}


checkTable(schemaTables, function (result) {
  // here result will be true or false, you can do whatever you want
  // inside the callback with result, but it will be called ASYNCHRONOUSLY
  console.log(result);
});
```

Notice that as i said before, you can't have a function that returns a true or false value synchronously, so the only thing you can do is passing a callback to `checkTable` that will execute as soon as the result is ready (when all the promises fulfill or when one of them rejects).
Or you can `return Promise.all(asyncTables)` and call `then` on `checkTable` it self, but i'll leave you this as exercise.
For more info about promises check:

- The bluebird [website](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)
- This wonderful [article](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) from Nolan Lawson

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cluk3 for the very comprehensive answer.  I actually solved it myself by using the .every method in the async library.  But yes, it was primarily due to both my misunderstanding regarding returns and asynchronous vs synchronous.

```
var checkTablesExist = function () {
    // make sure that all tables exist
    function checkTable(key, done) {
    dbInstance.schema.hasTable(key)
        .then(function(exists) {
            return done(exists);
            });
        }

    async.every(schemaTables, checkTable, 
        function(result) {
            return result;
        });
};

console.log(checkTablesExist());
// will now print true or false correctly
```